# Find and solve a recurrence relation for the number of n-digit ternary sequences with no consecutive digits being equal

Tags: combinatorics, recurrence-relations

I had a question that I need some help on:

> Find and solve a recurrence relation for the number of n-digit ternary sequences with no consecutive digits being equal

As I worked this out, I realized, I'm not sure what $a_n$ is supposed to be counting. Could someone help me figure out the initial conditions (maybe up to like $a_4$ or something) so I could solve this problem. Please provide a detailed explanation of how you got to those initial conditions so I can better understand the problem. Any hints on how to solve the problem are also encouraged!
Thanks in advanced for your help, I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

$a_n$ is supposed to be the number of sequences of `a`, `b`, and `c` of length $n$ that don't have a pair of matching consecutive letters. For example, $a_3$ is 12 because there are 12 such sequences of length 3:

```
aba
abc
aca
acb
bab
bac
bca
bcb
cab
cac
cba
cbc
```

The recurrence should express $a_{n+1}$ in terms of $a_n$: if you knew how many such sequences there were of length $n$, how can you use that to determine the number of sequences of length $n+1$?

The initial condition would simply be the value of $a_0$ or $a_1$: how many such sequences are there of length 0 or 1?

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. So $a_1$ = 3, $a_2$ = 6 and $a_4$ would be 24? If that would be the case, then would the recursive relation be $a_n$ = $a_(n-1)$ * 2? This would be because for each additional number in the sequence (e.g. a one digit sequence, a two digit sequence, 3 digit,....) you would have only 2 choices of an option. What I mean can be best shown by an example:

Comment: So for a two digit sequence you have 3 options for a number for the first space, then two options for the second space. For a three digit sequence you have 3 options for a number in the first space, but only two options for the next two spaces.
Is my logic correct on this? Is my answer correct?

Comment: That sounds correct to me.